# ServletRegistrationBean cannot be resolved in SpringBoot

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I am working in a SpringBoot project based on

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

I updated the pom to

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

to have the last version but after that I can't compile the project anymore because I have this problem:

```
The import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean cannot be 
 resolved
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved !

`org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean` was deprecated in 1.4 in favour or `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean`. The former was removed in 1.5 since it was deprecated